# How would I draw random samples from a 2 dimensional density plot?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, statistics, probability

I have (x,y) coordinate pairs that I've plotted using sns.kdeplot. I want to randomly sample coordinates based on the 2D probability density function. How would I do that?

Here's some dummy data:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

x_values = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=100)
y_values = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=100)

coordinate_pairs = list(zip(x_values,y_values))

sns.kdeplot(x_values, y_values)
```

I'm able to plot the probability density function, but how would I randomly sample (x,y) coordinate tuples from this distribution? Obviously the real data isn't completely random like dummy data provided above.

Thanks so much and have a great day.

Comment: Sampling from a kernel density estimate is equivalent to sampling your original data set (with replacement) and adding zero mean noise. Depending on what you need to do, that might be convenient.

Answer (score 2):

Seaborn doesn't return the object that contains the kernel density estimate.
However if you look in the code, you can see that they use `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` for that. So you can do the same outside of plotting.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

# random 2d values
X = np.random.randn(1000, 2)

# fit kernel density estimate. needs to be transposed for the function
kde = gaussian_kde(X.T)

# now you can resample from it
# transpose to have same shape as X
Y = kde.resample(1000).T
```